# Node.js enviando comando GET

Tags: html, node.js, http-request, xmlhttprequest

Olá! estou com problemas para utilizar o comando GET /teste nesse caso, no qual não retorna nenhuma informação.

**Código Node.js**

```
var http = require("http").createServer(servidor);
var express = require('express');
var io = require("socket.io").listen(http);
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");
var recebido;

var contentTypes = {
    js: 'text/javascript',
    css: 'text/css',
    json: 'application/json',
    png: 'image/png',
    jpg: 'image/png',
    wav: 'audio/wav'
};

function servidor(req, res) {
    var contentType = 'text/html';
    var filePath = '.' + req.url;
    if (filePath == './' || filePath == './index.html') filePath = './index.html';
    else contentType = contentTypes[req.url.split('.').pop()];

    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
        if (error) {
            if (error.code == 'ENOENT') {
                fs.readFile('./404.html', function(error, content) {
                    res.writeHead(200, {
                        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
                    });
                    res.end(content, 'utf-8');
                });
            } else {
                res.writeHead(500);
                res.end('Ooops... houve um erro: ' + error.code + ' ..\n');
                res.end();
            }
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': contentType
            });
            res.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });
}

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.on('mensagem', function(msg) {
        console.log('Recebido: ' + msg);
        recebido = msg;
    });
});

app.get('/teste', function(req, res) {
    res.charset = 'UTF-8'
    res.send(recebido);
});


http.listen(5000, "192.168.0.108", function() {
    var host = http.address().address;
    var port = http.address().port;
    console.log('Exemplo na URL http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Ao utilizar o comando GET /teste ou http://192.168.0.108/teste, a página carrega em branco

Comment: `res.end(fs.readFileSync` é muito má ideia. Claro que para quem começa com Node.js não é fácil saber isso. Queres usar só Node "nativo" ou podes juntar à aplicação uma framework de Node para um servidor com mais funcionalidade?

Comment: @sergio a ideia é utilizar o Node somente para comunicação com o Arduino (ESP8266 via comando GET) e HTML com o Socket i.o. Qual é a sua ideia?

Comment: Em relação ao `fs.readFileSync` seria melhor fazer isso `async`, carregar o ficheiro em cache e servir de memória. Para servir ficheiros deves enviar o header com o tipo de ficheiro e tens de ler/interpretar cada url pedido e servir o ficheiro. Com o `express.js` por exemplo fica mais fácil, senão tens de fazer algo assim: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29046869/2256325

Comment: Luiz, testa esta ideia: https://jsfiddle.net/cezr3wzp/2/ se funcionar junto como resposta

Comment: @M8n executando pelo seu código, continua mesma coisa

Comment: À partida `var filePath = '.' + req.url;` converte o url no nome do ficheiro e o Node deve ir buscar, sem teres de especificar mais ficheiros. O `index.html` especifica-se pois é o unico que pode abrir só com o url vazio. Ou seja `default`. Testa.

Comment: O socket io é para comunicação/chat entre clientes. É isso que precisas? Se só tens ficheiros de html simples não precisas disso.

Answer (score 1):

```
var http = require("http").createServer(servidor);
var io = require("socket.io").listen(http);
var fs = require("fs");

function servidor(req, res){
    if (req.url.indexOf('/') != -1) {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(fs.readFileSync("index.html"));
    }

    if (req.url.indexOf('css/bootstrap.min.css') != -1) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": 'text/css'});
        res.end(fs.readFileSync("css/bootstrap.min.css"));
    }

    if (req.url.indexOf('css/sb-admin.css') != -1) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": 'text/css'});
        res.end(fs.readFileSync("css/sb-admin.css"));
    }

    if (req.url.indexOf('font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') != -1) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": 'text/css'});
        res.end(fs.readFileSync("font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"));
    }
}

io.on("connection", function(socket){
    socket.on('mensagem', function(msg) {
        console.log('Recebido: ' + msg);
    });
});

http.listen(5000, "127.0.0.1", function () {
    var host = http.address().address;
    var port = http.address().port;

    console.log('Exemplo na URL http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: Por que vocês estão usando 'socket.io' ? Se for apenas para pegar o evento 'connection', o próptio objeto 'http' acima também recebe este evento.

Comment: @JoséX. eu fiz conforme o módulo do site do Socket i.o. Qual seria a sua ideia?

Comment: Neste exemplo não precisa de `socket.io`...em lugar de `io.on("connection)` poderia ser `http.on("connection")`. O módulo `socket.io` não está agregando nenhuma funcionalidade.

Comment: @JoséX. `socket.io` serve para criar um conexão WebSocket.

Comment: Mas esse exemplo não usa websocket, portanto não precisa de socket.io.

Comment: @JoséX. Meu HTML está enviando informações para o Socket... Tem como eu mudar o código do Node para que funcione o Socket i.o e também o GET /teste?